# How to prevent node js from serving .git folders and all the files under .git

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, .htaccess, security

I know that using `.htaccess` file can restrict files to be served under .git but how do i acheive the same if i'm using node.js server. I use forever to start/stop the servers.

Below is the code.

````
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var request = require("request");
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const app = express();

//app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

dotenv.config();

var environment = process.env.NODE_ENV;
var endpoint = process.env.AUTOMATION_API_ENDPOINT;
var port = process.env.PORT;

console.log('Environment : '+ environment);
console.log('Server Port : '+ port);
console.log('BackEnd server Endpoint : '+ endpoint);

var supplierId = null;
var supplyApiEndpoint = null;

app.get("/", function(req,res,next){
   var env=null;
   var url = endpoint+'/v1/supply/qa/env';
     require('http').get(url, (resp) => {
         resp.setEncoding('utf8');
         resp.on('data', function (response) {
             var body = JSON.parse(response);
             var supplyApiEndpoint = body.endpoint;
             console.log("Endpoint: "+supplyApiEndpoint);
             res.render('index',{env: supplyApiEndpoint});
         });
 });
})```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) is a tool for ensuring that a given script runs continuously and not a web framework.

To serve your files you will need to use a web framework like [express](https://expressjs.com/) and you will be able to ignore some directories serving only the files you need, for example, to serve your views directory:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/yourViewDirectory'));
```

or adding some rules using regex to ignore the files:

```
app.use([/^\/public\/secure($|\/)/, /(.*)\.js\.map$/, '/public'], express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

You can use other node.js web frameworks to do the same as [fastify](https://www.fastify.io/) or [koa](https://koajs.com/).

Comment: app.get("/", function(req,res,next){
   var env=null;
   var url = endpoint+'/v1/supply/qa/env';
     require('http').get(url, (resp) => {
         resp.setEncoding('utf8');
         resp.on('data', function (response) {
             var body = JSON.parse(response);
             var supplyApiEndpoint = body.endpoint;
             console.log("Endpoint: "+supplyApiEndpoint);
             res.render('index',{env: supplyApiEndpoint})
           }
         });
 });
})

It serves the files under .git folder as well (config file). How can i change this to restrict serving config files

Comment: I was able to resolve this, thanks @valdeci for pointing me into right direction. I moved all the html,css, views to public folder and used 
```app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/public/views'));```